# wcstombs_s "Cannot convert argument" DirectX-11

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer, size-t

Fist things first - Full error:

```
Error   3   error C2664: 'errno_t wcstombs_s(size_t *,char *,size_t,const wchar_t *,size_t)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned int *' to 'size_t *'    C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\DirectxTEST\Win32Project4\D3dclass.cpp    88  1   Win32Project4
```

I know whats causing this error(I think), I'm just stuck on what is "size_t*", because I've checked and my statment that I use wcstombs_s goes: unsigned int, char[128], int, WCHAR, int. This is the function with said line in, the header file that goes with the class it's in(incase somehow this is a #include error), and then the entire class, it's really long and 90% of it is irrelevent, but just to provide context incase it's nessicery.

Main code:

```
error = wcstombs_s(&stringLength, m_videoCardDescription, 128, adapterDesc.Description, 128);
if (error != 0){
    return false;
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef _D3DCLASS_H_
#define _D3DCLASS_H_
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx11.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <D3DCommon.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx10math.h>

class D3DClass{
public:
    D3DClass();
    D3DClass(const D3DClass&);
    ~D3DClass();

    bool Initialize(int, int, bool, HWND, bool, float, float);
    void Shutdown();

void BeginScene(float, float, float, float);
void EndScene();

ID3D11Device* GetDevice();
ID3D11DeviceContext* GetDeviceContext();

void GetProjectionMatrix(D3DXMATRIX&);
void GetWorldMatrix(D3DXMATRIX&);
void GetOrthoMatrix(D3DXMATRIX&);

void GetVideoCardInfo(char*, int&);
private:
bool m_vsync_enabled;
int m_videoCardMemory;
char m_videoCardDescription[128];
IDXGISwapChain* m_swapChain;
ID3D11Device* m_device;
ID3D11DeviceContext* m_deviceContext;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* m_renderTargetView;
ID3D11Texture2D* m_depthStencilBuffer;
ID3D11DepthStencilState* m_depthStencilState;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* m_depthStencilView;
ID3D11RasterizerState* m_rasterState;
D3DXMATRIX m_projectionMatrix;
D3DXMATRIX m_worldMatrix;
D3DXMATRIX m_orthoMatrix;
};
#endif
```

Full Class

```
#include "D3Dclass.h"

D3DClass::D3DClass(){
m_swapChain = 0;
m_device = 0;
m_deviceContext = 0;
m_renderTargetView = 0;
m_depthStencilBuffer = 0;
m_depthStencilState = 0;
m_depthStencilView = 0;
m_rasterState = 0;
}
D3DClass::D3DClass(const D3DClass& other){

}
D3DClass::~D3DClass(){

}
bool D3DClass::Initialize(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, bool vsync, HWND hwnd, bool                   fullscreen, float screenDepth, float screenNear){
HRESULT result;
IDXGIFactory* factory;
IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
IDXGIOutput* adapterOutput;
unsigned int numModes, i, numerator, denominator, stringLength;
DXGI_MODE_DESC* displayModeList;
DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
int error;
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferPtr;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc;
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
float fieldOfView, screenAspect;
m_vsync_enabled = vsync;

//Create a DirectX Graphics Interface Library
result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}
//Create apapter for video card
result = factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}
//Enemerate the moniter/screen
result = adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &adapterOutput);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}
//Get the number of nodes that fit in the DXGI below for moniter
result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,         DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, NULL);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}
//Create list to hold possible display modes for moniter
displayModeList = new DXGI_MODE_DESC[numModes];
if (!displayModeList){
    return false;
}
//Fill display mode structure
result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, displayModeList);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}
//Find display mode that matches screen width and height
//Then store numerator and denominator of refresh rate
for (i = 0; i < numModes; i++){
    if (displayModeList[i].Width == (unsigned int)screenWidth){
        if (displayModeList[i].Height == (unsigned int)screenHeight){
            numerator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Numerator;
            denominator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Denominator;
        }
    }
}
//Get video card desc
result = adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}
//Store dedicated video card memory in megabytes
m_videoCardMemory = (int)(adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory / 1024 / 1024);

//Convert video card name to char and store it
error = wcstombs_s(&stringLength, m_videoCardDescription, 128, adapterDesc.Description, 128);
if (error != 0){
    return false;
}
//Release display mode list
delete[] displayModeList;
displayModeList = 0;

//Release adapter output
adapterOutput->Release();
adapterOutput = 0;

//Release the adapter
adapter->Release();
adapter = 0;

//Release the Factory
factory->Release();
factory = 0;

//Initialize swap chain description
ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));

//Set to a single back buffer
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;

//Set sizes of back buffer
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;

//Set regular 32bit surface for back buffer
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;

//Set refresh rate for back buffer
if (m_vsync_enabled){
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = numerator;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = denominator;
}
else{
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
}
//Set usage of back buffer
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;

//Set handle for the window to render into
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

//Turn multisampling off
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

//Set to full screen/windowed
if (fullscreen){
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = false;
}
else{
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;
}

//Thing?
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

//Discard buffer contents after presenting
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

//Don't set advanced flags
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

//Set feature level to DirectX-11
featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

//Create the Swap Chain, Direct3D device and Direct3D device context
//Turn D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE to D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE to support directx10 or lower
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, &featureLevel, 1,   D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}

//Get pointer to back buffer
result = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferPtr);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}

//Create render target view with back buffer pointer
result = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, NULL, &m_renderTargetView);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}

//Release pointer to back buffer
backBufferPtr->Release();
backBufferPtr = 0;

//Initialize depth buffer desc
ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

//Depth Buffer Description
depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

//Create texture for depth buffer
result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}

//Initialize stencil state desc
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

//Setup desc
depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

//Create depth stencil state
result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}

//Set depth stencil state
m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);

//Initialize depth stencil view
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

//Setup depth stencil view
depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

//Create depth stencil view
result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc,   &m_depthStencilView);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}

//Bind render target view and depth stencil buffer to output render pipeline
m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);

//Setup raster desc(determines how polygons are rendered)
rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

//Create raster state
result = m_device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_rasterState);
if (FAILED(result)){
    return false;
}

//Set raster state
m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);

//Setup viewport for rendering
viewport.Width = (float)screenWidth;
viewport.Height = (float)screenHeight;
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

//Create viewport
m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

//Setup projection matrix
fieldOfView = (float)D3DX_PI / 4.0f;
screenAspect = (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight;

//Create projecttion matrix for 3d rendering
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&m_projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, screenAspect, screenNear, screenDepth);

//Initialize world matrix to identity matrix
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&m_worldMatrix);

//Create Orthographic projection matrix for 2D rendering
D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&m_orthoMatrix, (float)screenWidth, (float)screenHeight, screenNear, screenDepth);

return true;
}
void D3DClass::Shutdown(){
//Set to windowed
if (m_swapChain){
    m_swapChain->GetFullscreenState(false, NULL);
}
if (m_rasterState){
    m_rasterState->Release();
    m_rasterState = 0;
}
if (m_depthStencilBuffer){
    m_depthStencilBuffer->Release();
    m_depthStencilBuffer = 0;
}
if (m_depthStencilState){
    m_depthStencilState->Release();
    m_depthStencilState = 0;
}
if (m_depthStencilView){
    m_depthStencilView->Release();
    m_depthStencilView = 0;
}
if (m_deviceContext){
    m_deviceContext->Release();
    m_deviceContext = 0;
}
if (m_swapChain){
    m_swapChain->Release();
    m_swapChain = 0;
}
return;
}
void D3DClass::BeginScene(float red, float blue, float green, float alpha){
float color[4];

//Setup colors
color[0] = red;
color[1] = green;
color[2] = blue;
color[3] = alpha;

//Clear back buffer
m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, color);

//Clear depth buffer
m_deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

return;
}
void D3DClass::EndScene(){
//Present back buffer to screen
if (m_vsync_enabled){
    //Lock to screen refresh rate
    m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
}
else{
    //Present as fast as possible
    m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
return;
}
//Helper functions
ID3D11Device* D3DClass::GetDevice(){
return m_device;
}
ID3D11DeviceContext* D3DClass::GetDeviceContext(){
return m_deviceContext;
}
void D3DClass::GetProjectionMatrix(D3DXMATRIX& projectionMatrix){
m_projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
return;
}
void D3DClass::GetWorldMatrix(D3DXMATRIX& worldMatrix){
m_worldMatrix = worldMatrix;
return;
}
void D3DClass::GetOrthoMatrix(D3DXMATRIX& orthoMatrix){
m_orthoMatrix = orthoMatrix;
return;
}
void D3DClass::GetVideoCardInfo(char* cardName, int& memory){
strcpy_s(cardName, 128, m_videoCardDescription);
memory = m_videoCardMemory;
return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change the type of `stringLength` to `size_t` or pass `NULL` as as the first argument to `wcstombs_s` instead.